# Black window when loading any model

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, blender

I have tried to load a model and display it in my window for about 2 hours, but now i surrender. I tried about 10 different models that i downloaded from https://sketchfab.com, but none is displayed, i just get a black window. I searched for help in the web another 20 minutes now but as i am not very experienced in libgdx, i cant adapt the "solutions" i found to my programm. I hope you can help me!

Another question i have is, that if there was any way to use models with more indexes than the `short` value.

model i used: https://sketchfab.com/models/042201dac61041fabb88f483368daa3f

my code:

```
public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter
{
private PerspectiveCamera cam;
private CameraInputController camController;
private ModelBatch modelBatch;
private AssetManager assets;
private Array<ModelInstance> instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();
private Environment environment;
private boolean loading;

@Override
public void create () {
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new PointLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f, 1f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(1f, 1f, 1f);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.near = 0.1f;
    cam.far = 300f;
    cam.update();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);

    assets = new AssetManager();
    assets.load("basic.g3db", Model.class);
    loading = true;
}

private void doneLoading() {
    Model ship = assets.get("basic.g3db", Model.class);
    ModelInstance shipInstance = new ModelInstance(ship);
    instances.add(shipInstance);
    loading = false;
}

@Override
public void render () {
    if (loading && assets.update())
        doneLoading();
    camController.update();

    Gdx.gl20.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 
    Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
 }

 @Override
 public void dispose () {
    modelBatch.dispose();
    instances.clear();
    assets.dispose();
 }

 public void resume () {
 }

 public void resize (int width, int height) {
 }

 public void pause () {
 }
}
```